# Another 'no identities are available for signing' issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

So i'm attempting to submit my app to the app store and getting the 'no identities are available for signing' error.

Ive gone through and remade my distribution certificate about 5 times so far in the provisioning portal, re-downloaded it (through xcode) each time and to no avail it still gives me the error.

Ive adjusted the code signing in the build settings to be set to the 'iPhone Distribution: (my certificate name)'  as well as making sure my bundle identifiers match.

Ive restarted XCode multiple times and nothing seems to be working.

ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning your project? This oftentimes resolves such issues with my own projects.

Product ==> Clean

Comment: it had no effect.  same result